# Howto convert a byte array to mail attachment

Tags: c#, email

I have byte array which is essentially an encoded .docx retrieved from the DB. I try to convert this byte[] to it's original file and make it as an attachment to a mail without having to store it first as file on disk.
What's the best way to go about this?

```
public MailMessage ComposeMail(string mailFrom, string mailTo, string copyTo, byte[] docFile)
{
    var mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.From = new MailAddress(mailFrom);

    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailTo));
    mail.Body = "mail with attachment";

    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;

    //Attach the byte array as .docx file without having to store it first as a file on disk?
    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("docFile");
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    return mail;
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is an [overload of the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sdktyws.aspx) of `Attachment` that takes a stream. You can pass in the file directly by constructing a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) using the `byte[]`:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(docFile);
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(stream, "document.docx");
```

The second argument is the name of the file, from which the mime-type will be inferred. Remember to call [`Dispose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227422.aspx) on the `MemoryStream` once you have finished with it.